# JFrame laying out multiple JPanels

Tags: java, panel, gridbaglayout

[image: The Panel I am making]

I am not sure how I could create a panel like this. I could have the main panel as a borderlayout and set the login screen panel to the page_end but then the forums and faqs also have to be on the page_end..... somehow the login screen panel and the forums and faqs panel has to share the page_end together. Is there someway I could do this or maybe some BETTER way? This has been confusing me for about 2 hours and I don't understand how I would do this.

Right now I have 3 panels and 1 frame. 1 is the main panel that is added to the main frame. The 2 other panels are the loginscreen panel and the forums and faqs panel. Here is the code.

```
    private void createView() {

    //Created essential details for the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Name of the game");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Defining layouts and panels + giving them layouts
    JPanel pMain = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(pMain);
    pMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pMain.add(pLogin, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    JPanel pInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pMain.add(pInfo, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the component layout

### Source

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Name of the game");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Defining layouts and panels + giving them layouts
        JPanel pMain = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(pMain);
        pMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel bottomComponentsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel pLogin = new JPanel();
        pLogin.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        JPanel pInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pInfo.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        pInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;

        bottomComponentsPanel.add(pLogin, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        bottomComponentsPanel.add(pInfo, constraints);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        bottomPanel.add(bottomComponentsPanel);

        pMain.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
```

### Display

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of layouts... it's a bit messy and I like what you did but is there any way to make the plogin panel literally in the bottom middle and the pinfo panel next to it like my picture? The one you made has the plogin panel and bit to the right.

Comment: Although it's a bit messy this is a perfect panel that I can customize a bit to make it more appealing to me! Thank you so much, you made my day!

Comment: Glad to hear this @JohnnyInno1! Thanks for accepting the answer. :) BTW, I tried many ways to get what you wanted and had to insert more code to get it to the shape. :)

Comment: Yep no problem, I already added some of my own ideas into it  and it looks great :). If you could though maybe send the code to your updated method that would be awesome, I really am interested in it.